# What is the best SSIS Tasks for String Parsing database fields

Tags: sql-server, ssis, string

What is/are the best SSIS Tasks to use in order to search for string patterns.  This relates to standardizing address information.  My developer does not have a confident grasp on using Regular Expressions in his code.

Comment: `standardizing address information`... Having worked in the print and mail industry for 5 years, let me just say the money you will spend on developing your own solution versus buying an off the shelf product is going to be insane, at least for the US Postal Service. It starts out looking like something for regex to handle - I just want to convert Street  and ste. to St but then you run into stupid stuff like South Street Boulevard. Yes, the street's name is actually Street but your regex converts to S St Blvd which is then undeliverable. Or people living on North East street...

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in address clean-up task in SSIS. However, there are plenty of [Examples](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7) of regular expressions that could be implemented with a Script Task. They can be implemented in VB or C# and knowledge of such a transform is something that any ETL developer should be able to do, [or learn to do](http://adamprescott.net/2012/02/29/simple-regular-expression-us-street-address-parser-in-c/). They don't need to memorize Regular Expressions or become an expert, but they should be able to create a basic implementation and test/verify the patterns created and shared by others.

This is a great professional development opportunity for your developer! I'd suggest giving them the time, support, and encouragement to expand their development skills with this... along with encouraging their own use of this site and search engines to navigate their way through a solution. Whatever you do and search for though, start by breaking the address down into component parts. You will find numerous US Postal Code validation regular expressions, that are relatively easy to comprehend and apply.

If you do not have the time or capability there are third party packages, like [Task Factory](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory), that have components that can address this need.

On the higher end of development skills (used to ensure a true address, not just standardizing text) is using a web service like Bing Maps to geocode/resolve addresses. Such a service should be able to not only re-fromat addresses to correct values, but correct or identify bad data issues that may exist in your data. This would be a much more advanced solution.